# How to get WCF to work across countries with Internet censorship?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, proxy

Suppose I have a WCF service which I need to host on a server in a country which blocks access to many sites.

So if I host my WCF for testing purposes on a server that is not in such a country, it works perfectly — but whenever I try to deploy it to any server in this country I can’t access it.

Are there any workarounds for that?

Comment: Please don’t vote to close this question. The question itself is not localised. I’ve edited it to be more applicable by removing references to the specific country.

Comment: While IANAL, isn't what you're asking illegal in the country you're talking about?

Comment: @John [Kingdom of SA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saudi_Arabia)

Comment: @Cameron MacFarland: It may be, or it may not be. I think we should let the OP make this call and get on with answering the question.

Comment: omg ! do you think that using WCF is illegal !! its a common problem many countries have proxies to block porn sites and ilegal sites from thier childrens, and the caus eof this is i cant use WCF ! nethier normal http listener !

Comment: Are you able to access Internet from the server? If so you can try to use Azure service bus and relay communication with your service.

Comment: Btw. based on edited question, I don't understand why did you close it.

Comment: @ Ladislav Mrnka, yes im able to access the internet from the server

Comment: @ Cameron MacFarland, how can using a webservice in a country be illegal ?

Comment: @Zeus It's not using a webservice, it's circumventing censorship

Comment: Trying to bypass a web filter will be illegal in the country that has the filter.

Comment: the purpose of the web filter is not to block WCF, or any technology that is based on HTTP.

Comment: i got it working now,

transparent proxies used to censorship would never block wcf , it was a silly problem in my windows server 2008 which is :

Start > administrative tools > server manager > features > add feature > .netframwork 3.5 > activate WCF!!!